# Custom Layer with pytorch autograd makes gradient error when training

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm a beginner in Pytorch and want to make a custom layer, PACT Function, "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.06085.pdf". I implemented this layer and replaced all ReLU functions in ResNet. But When I started to train my model, this error occurred.

**RuntimeError: Function _pact_functionBackward returned an invalid gradient at index 1 - got [] but expected shape compatible with [1]**

PACT Class:

```
class PACT(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_bits=4):
    super(PACT, self).__init__()

    self.num_bits = num_bits
    self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([5.]), requires_grad=True)

    self.pact_function = PACT_function()
    self.pact_quantize = PACT_quantize(self.alpha, self.num_bits)

  def forward(self, input):
    y = self.pact_function(input, self.alpha)
    yq = self.pact_quantize(y)

  return yq
```

And how to forward and backward the activation with "pact_function":

```
def PACT_function():
  class _pact_function(torch.autograd.function):

    # See https://github.com/obilaniu/GradOverride/blob/master/functional.py
    # See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.06085.pdf

    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, x, alpha):
      ctx.save_for_backward(x, alpha)
      return x.clamp(min=0.).min(alpha)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
      x, alpha = ctx.saved_variables

      lt0      = x < 0
      gta      = x > alpha
      gi       = 1.0-lt0.float()-gta.float()

      grad_x    = grad_output*gi
      grad_alpha = torch.sum(grad_output*x.ge(alpha).float())

      return grad_x, grad_alpha   # why grad_x, None acts?? but this makes the values of alpha same in all layers!

  return _pact_function.apply
```

This is very odd because if I remove grad_alpha, returns like grad_x, None, then the code acts. However, when I print the values of alpha in my model (ResNet), the values are all same even if those PACT layers are different layers.

- Epoch: 10 | LR: 0.01000  [============================ 196/196
  ===========================>]  Step: 61ms | Tot: 22s604ms | Loss: 0.555 | Acc: 80.896% (40448/50000)
- PACT() Parameter containing: tensor([4.5349], device='cuda:0',   requires_grad=True)
- PACT() Parameter containing: tensor([4.5349],       device='cuda:0',
  requires_grad=True)
- PACT() Parameter containing:          tensor([4.5349],
  device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
- PACT()          Parameter    containing: tensor([4.5349], device='cuda:0',             requires_grad=True)
- PACT() Parameter containing: tensor([4.5349], device='cuda:0',    requires_grad=True)

So, I'm wondered why returning (grad_x, None) acts, not (grad_x, grad_alpha), and why alpha parameters are same in all layers when using (grad_x, None) with nn.Parameter. 
It's really grateful if you have some answers.

Comment: It is really hard to reproduce the issue without the rest of the code, but I can see that `alpha` is a 1d tensor with the size of five, however, the result of `torch.sum` is a single value. Therefore, their shape does not match. When you return `None` instead of a single value, the code will run; however, its value will not be updated.

Comment: thank you so much that was the problem. I change the dtype of gradient and the code acts well. Besides, I still dont know why the alpha values are same when using nn.Parameter